# Analyze the following code, which exception does it display? (Exception handling, java)

Tags: java, exception

```
class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      String s = "5.6";
      Integer.parseInt(s); // Cause a NumberFormatException

      int i = 0;
      int y = 2 / i;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
      System.out.println("NumberFormatException");
    }
    catch (RuntimeException ex) {
      System.out.println("RuntimeException");
    }
  }
}
```

The correct answer is that the program has a compilation error. I thought that the `catch (Exception ex)` would catch all exceptions including `NumberFormatException`, that it was a general exception that caught them all?

Comment: well an exception(runtime) is something different then a compile time(compilation) error.

Comment: Unreachable catch block for RuntimeException. It is already handled by the catch block for Exception

Comment: Because a `RuntimeException` is already a `Exception`

Comment: Oh I see, thank you! I read that we should handle the most specific exceptions first but I didn't realize it would lead to an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The block:

```
catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println("NumberFormatException");
}
```

will catch **all** the exceptions, as the `Exception` class is the base class for all the exceptions.

When you catch `Exception`, you catch all the exceptions that `extend` `Exception`, which, all the exceptions do. Hence it produces the error that **RuntimeException has already been caught**